# Keyboard shorcuts like copy, paste, select all not working 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcuts, paste, copy

Fresh install of 14.04 unity ubuntu. These shortcuts don't work.
Was not able to find the solution. Has anybody has the same problem?

Comment: Could you give more detail? In what program were you trying to use these shortcuts? **Terminal** is a common exception were you need to use `Shift + Ctrl + C` for _Copy_ , `Shift + Ctrl + V` for _Paste_.

Comment: Hi! it's in all programs. Email, webbroswer, spreadsheet, text editor.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand this may be a bug in 14.04 Unity. See bug report here looks like a few others have had some problems

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1224732

Looks like this was for 13.10 but seems can affect 14.04 unity desktop as well. Maybe try using Compiz to set your own shortcuts up and see if that helps...

I am running Xubuntu 14.04 and don't have any problems. Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I had been using 14.04 with lubuntu also without problem. I will try compiz.

Comment: I didn't manage to make it work with compiz.